# JPQL Joint table

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have a Collaborator and Intervention table .

Collaborator (Id Collab, Collab Name, address Collab)
Intervention (id_Interv, Nom_Interv, End_date, Id_collab) ("the entity response contains a collaborator type object)

```
@Entity
public class Collaborateur implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long idcollaborateur;
   private String nomCollaborateur;
   ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Intervention implements Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long idInterv;
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   private Date dateEndInterv;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "idCollaborateur")
   private Collaborateur collaborateur;
   ...
 }
```

how i can Select all Collaborators (List ) doesn't have any Intervention for now ..
ie Collaborators who doesn't have intervention or the dateEndInterv of all of their intervention less than datetimenow

I hope to have been clear,My essay:

```
SELECT c
FROM Collaborateur c LEFT JOIN c.Intervention i
WHERE (i.dateFinIntervention<?1 or i.dateFinIntervention IS NULL)
```

I worked on spring data

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a new relationship between Collaborateur and Intervention, like an `@OneToMany`:

```
@Entity
public class Collaborateur implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long idcollaborateur;
   private String nomCollaborateur;

   @OneToMany
   private Set<Intervention> interventions;
   ...
}
```

So, your JPQL will be:

```
SELECT c
FROM Collaborateur c 
LEFT JOIN c.interventions i
WHERE (i.dateEndInterv < ?1 OR i.dateEndInterv IS NULL)
```